# Image size in aspect fit in UITableviewCell not loading properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImage` to download image over internet and display in `TableViewCell`.My image is not fit exactly over the cell when download but when i scroll it fits perfectly.my code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is

```
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! AgentPostTableViewCell

        let str = apiData[indexPath.row].valueForKey("multiple_images")?.objectAtIndex(0) as? String
        cell.agentimage.image = nil
        cell.agentimage.clipsToBounds = true
        if str != nil && str?.isEmpty == false{
            let url = NSURL(string: imageUrl + str!)

            let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
                if tableView.visibleCells.contains(cell){
                    cell.setPostedImage(cell.agentimage.image!)
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                cell.layoutSubviews()

                }
            }
            cell.agentimage.sd_setImageWithURL(url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "o"), completed: block)
            cell.setPostedImage(cell.agentimage.image!)
            print("post image " + imageUrl + str!)
        }
```

For resizing upon download i'm using this code

```
func setPostedImage(image : UIImage) {

    let aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height

    aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: agentimage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: agentimage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: aspect, constant: 0.0)

    agentimage.image = image
}
```

Problem is that when is downloaded it doesn't fit properly on the view but after i scroll it properly fits inside the view.

before scrolling

[image: this is the loaded view]

after I Scroll and come back this is the view[image]

Comment: Is this a dynamic height tableview?

Comment: yes using UITableViewAutomaticDimension and EstimatedheightForRow

Comment: As I say you create constraint but don't activate it. In this realization the constraint don't have any effect on layout. But if you call **[... setActive:YES]** you will have other problem. You will have more that one constraint after perform scrolling.

Comment: @Sergey You will have more that one constraint after perform scrolling. what do you mean by it, as i said after scrolling the view is perfectly resized.

Comment: Can you screenshot the table view cell and add it to the question?

Comment: Also do you think your estimation is close enough to the final height of the cell.

Comment: @agibson007 edited with the screenshots

Comment: Make sure you are using aspect fill.

Comment: @agibson007 if i'm using aspectFill then still the result is same. the size is not proper and it is still giving the space below and above.

Comment: what priority do you have on the aspect ratio constraint

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I think you need to get the tableview to update.  Add a fixed Height Constraint on the cell that you can manipulate and then change it dynamically.  Here is an example

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "funCell", for: indexPath) as! FunTableViewCell
    //your url will go here
    let url = URL(string: array[indexPath.row])!
    cell.agentimage.image = nil
    cell.agentimage.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
    cell.agentimage.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: {
        (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> Void in
        if image != nil{
            let aspect = image!.size.width / image!.size.height
            //or whatever width you are wanting to constrain it to
            let ourHeight = cell.bounds.width * aspect
            if cell.heightConstraint.constant != ourHeight{
                cell.heightConstraint.constant = ourHeight
                cell.agentimage.image = image
                //most important lines as it would make your constraint work
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }

        }
    })
    return cell
}
```

You can also reload the specific index path with

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

The check on the constraint is super important because there is no reason to reset it if it does not need reset. Also to help with smoothness you could hold a dictionary of the image sizes or aspect ratios so that you would not have to calculate each time.

Cheers

Comment: You also create constraint but don't activate it. This constraint don't have effect. But if you activate this constraint you will have more that one constraint when you try to scroll tableview.

Comment: @Sergey  the aspect constraint is actually the outlet of the constraint of aspect ratio from storyboard in  tableViewCell class

Comment: In your code you create new constraint **aspectConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: agentimage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: agentimage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: aspect, constant: 0.0)**

Comment: @Sergey here this is code for creating the aspect constraint    
internal var aspectConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint? {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != nil {
                agentimage.removeConstraint(oldValue!)
            }
            if aspectConstraint != nil {
                agentimage.addConstraint(aspectConstraint!)
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Sergey s point is true.  Probably should set to active. aspectConstraint.isActive = true.  give that a run

Comment: @agibson007 there is not property as .isActive as i'm trying to find this.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nslayoutconstraint scroll down to activating constraints or to go directly to it. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1527000-isactive

Comment: @agibson007 tried that as well before setting the image onto the image View , but still couldn't get through.

Comment: Arun K - Give the updated answer a test run.  you may have to modify it for your code.

Comment: Strangely with this snippet
tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.endUpdates()
my code works but still the updated is to wierd and it scrolls to anywhere in app while changing the height.

Comment: It is because it is asking the tableview to update. When the cell is created it does not have the image so the tableview does not know how big to make the cell.Also I would check for equality of the constraints so that it is not constantly resetting them on scroll when in some cases it would correct.  See my answer.

Comment: The check on constraints will fix that. That way it is not constantly updating. Check my answer how I only change the constraint if it needs it. You can also have it only update the index path example tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) but having a check on the constraint will fix a lot of this.

Comment: @ArunK did you ever resolve the issue with my suggestion and get the answer working properly?

Comment: Nope the answer was not working so i used prefetchdatasource protocol in tableView to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You create aspect constrain but don't activate it.

I would advise not to use the aspect constraint and replace it to image. contentMode

I think you need to use **scaleAspectFit** or **scaleAspectFill**

If you want to use constraint create it from storyboard, create IBOutlet in cell and change constant on it constraint.

Comment: Using ScaleAspectfit from the storyboard